# Unmangle C++ DLL Function Names

Tags: c

I have a dll which exports 3 function:

#### .h file

```
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall InitializeChangeNotify(void);
__declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(LPCWSTR AccountName,LPCWSTR FullName,LPCWSTR Password,BOOLEAN SetOperation);
__declspec(dllexport) NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(LPCWSTR UserName,ULONG RelativeId,LPCWSTR NewPassword);
}
```

#### .c file

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall InitializeChangeNotify(void)
{
    writeToLog("InitializeChangeNotify()");
    return TRUE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(LPCWSTR AccountName,LPCWSTR FullName,LPCWSTR Password,BOOLEAN SetOperation)
{
    writeToLog("PasswordFilter()");
    return TRUE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(LPCWSTR UserName,ULONG RelativeId,LPCWSTR NewPassword)
{
    writeToLog("PasswordChangeNotify()");
    return 0;
}
}
```

i compile in VS 2010.

I see the function names in depends like: `_InitializeChangeNotify@0, _PasswordChangeNotify@12`. How do I unmangle the functions?

Comment: Well, is it C or C++? Your title says C++, but your description and tags say C.

Comment: Not to mention that a C program won't like `extern "C"` very much.

Comment: Why do you want to unmangle the function name?  Those are the names the tools will expect  If you want 'clean' names so they can be used more easily in `GetProcAddress()` then I think you'll need a `.def` file.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like [`undname.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx) on windows is the '[`c++filt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt)' equivalent.

I've it under `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\undname.exe"` in my  PC.

From the page,

You can use the undname.exe to convert a decorated name to its undecorated form. For example,

```
C:\>undname ?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1981-2000. All rights reserved.Undecoration
of :- "?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z"
is :- "private: void __thiscall a::func1(int)"
```

Answer (score 1):

_xxx@x mean that this is __stdcall calling convention. Digit after @ mean summary size of arguments in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this.and solve it by specifying a def file.
e.g:

### a.def:

EXPORTS

### InitializeChangeNotify

in project setting, set Link>> Input>>Module definition file to a.def
and rebuild.
HTH